# Is the opposite of "like" "dislike" or "indifference/neutrality & dislike?"

Tags: semantics

I think most people think the opposite of "like" is "dislike," but when I think about it, I don't think this is true.

"Dislike" actually means that one regards the thing of interest with displeasure. But the opposite of "like" should just be anything that doesn't mean "like" and in this case it could mean "dislike" but it could also mean that one is indifferent/neutral (neither like or dislike) regarding the thing of interest.

So what is actually the opposite of "like?"

This leads me to my next question on if "I don't like X" is the same as "I dislike X?" Based on what I alluded to above, I think the two are different. The think the former doesn't necessarily mean you dislike X, as I think it necessarily covers the case where you feel neutral about X, but I feel most people would interpret "I don't like" as "I dislike."

Comment: This is really a philosophical question, rather than a grammatical one. The basic meanings of "like", "dislike", etc are given in dictionaries. Antonyms are less clear-cut than novices and amateurs think: there isn't a big list where every word X has a single antonym that always means not-X. Words mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: I think you have pointed out some good nuances among like, dislike, don't like etc so I think the difficulty is deciding on what 'opposite' means.

Comment: This has been discussed on ELU before. Whether 'opposite' means 'the polar opposite of a stance, attribute etc' or 'the absence of a stance, attitude etc' depends on one's stipulative definition (_stipulative definition_ rather than _precising definition_, as answers derived using them will conflict).

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/323016/142322) to a similar question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "dislike" and "don't like"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269244/is-there-a-difference-between-dislike-and-dont-like)

Comment: I don't like custard. I dislike custard. Same thing. The second is more formal.

Comment: We say: the opposite of hot is cold.  We do not say: the opposite of hot is "warm, cool, cold, or freezing".

Comment: See also [Is man the opposite of woman?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119231/is-man-the-opposite-of-woman/119235#119235) (not a duplicate)

Comment: Gradations / gradable antonyms ( hot [... warm ... tepid ... cool] ... cold) have been covered at [antonyms and mutually exclusive words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85459/antonyms-and-mutually-exclusive-words/85466#85466).

Answer (score 1):

> dislike (verb) = to not like
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dislike)

> **1: opposite** = completely different
>
> OR
>
> **2: opposite** = being in a position on the other side
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dislike)

The two senses of *opposite*, although connected, are not the same. It is important to distinguish them:

Using sense 1, *dislike* (even if it include indifference, neutrality or other shades of partiality), being "*not like*", is completely different from *like*, so they are opposites.

Using sense 2, *dislike* is completely different from *like* but because "*not like*" includes indifference, neutrality or other shades of partiality it cannot be seen as having a unique quality or position of being "on the other side" of *like*.

To give another example. In a completely *black* and *white* world, *black* and *white=not black* are *opposite* in sense 1, and in sense 2 (there being only two alternatives). But in a world of many colours, *black* and *white* are *opposite* only in sense 1 but not in sense 2.

Answer (score 1):

*Dislike* is the opposite of *like* in the sense of being its **gradable antonym**: the two concepts are at the opposite sides of a spectrum that also contains the intermediate concept of indifference. In the terminology of logic, *like* and *dislike* are contraries (but one cannot assume that the word *contrary* would be understood that way in an everyday conversation). On the other hand, *not like* (which includes both disliking and indifference) is the opposite of *like* in the sense of being its **complementary antonym**. In the terminology of logic, *like* and *not like* are contradictories. Both *dislike* and *not like* are thus the opposites of *like*; it's just that they are different kinds of opposites. The differences among different kinds of opposites are presented clearly in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)) on the topic.

The matter, however, gets more complicated when pragmatic considerations are added to the semantic ones. Even though *not like*, as a matter of semantics, includes indifference, we rarely say that we don't like something when we are indifferent to it. Indifference is more usually conveyed by something like 'I don't care' or 'it doesn't matter'. Because of that, one's saying that one doesn't like something is often taken to conversationally implicate that one dislikes it.

Answer (score 0):

Not liking and disliking are different notions but could be the same depending on the situation. For example. If you said to me: Do you like custard? I would say "I don't like custard" and I may add  "but I don't dislike it". In this sense 'not liking' does not imply a dislike. If you asked if I like root canal treatment I would say that "I don't like root canal treatment" and in this case I am definitely expressing dislike!

I think it depends on context - like so many things.

Answer (score 0):

These are what I call 'polarities' - ranges of opposites that exist in life.

You can consider them as 'a range' for example:

like  ----   disinterest (neutral)  ---- dislike

similarly:

love ----- neutrality ----- indifference
love ----- neutrality ----- hate

Polarities can have 'multiple ends' ie some have more than one 'opposite'. Think of the range of a polarity as shades of colours. In the middle, the two colours combine to create various shades of expression.

There are an infinite number of polarities, in life. after the emotions for example, jealousy - letting go, sad - happy, joy - despair, etc there are complex multi-word ones like 'successful at sports' - vs - 'failure at sports'. And everything else under the sun. Polarities form part of our 'palette of colours of expression'.

It is a philosophical question, as a commenter noted. So this is a philosophical answer.

Polarities
https://centerforbodylanguage.com/polarities/